# Resolve.conf Doesn't exist but can't make an one

Tags: drivers, dell, dns, ubuntu-drivers

So to start, I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Latitude with an i5 Processor (more hardware provide via specific request). I am trying to find a way to replace the /etc/resolv.conf file via the root terminal in the Grub menu, since a lack of drivers won't let me use my keyboard or mouse as soon as the login screen appears. Is there a way to create a new resolv.conf file if I can only access my bios menu and grub? For some background, my system seems to treat this file as if it still exist, but any attempt to delete it fails because, of course, it doesn't exist. Any attempt to overwrite fails because the file can't be found. How do I break this cycle. Also, as you might imagine, I may be in need of a completely new OS if there is no way to fix this. If you guys know of a process that allows me to create a bootable USB, plug it into the computer, and have the computer immediately install said OS when it's boots from the USB, like a windows CPU does with Ubuntu as an example. That would be great.

Comment: So... backing up here, your *real* issue is that you need to enable networking (and name resolution) while in the recovery shell?

Comment: I needed to use sudo apt-get update to download drivers that would allow me to login, but stuff wouldn't fetch, traced issue back to missing resolv.conf file. Networking, fetching, nothing very useful works without said file. So I'm at a point where I need to find a way to replace the file that is in this cycle of limbo as described above via the root terminal, or just replace my OS all together.

Comment: What does the /etc/resolve.conf file have to do with your keyboard/mouse not working? How did you determine this? See my answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

Usually,we can edit the `/etc/resolv.conf`. you can also use the graphical interfaces to edit the connect,fill in your dns server.

if you want create a bootable USB, you can use the unetbootin、Universal USB Installer etc.

Comment: What version of Linux allows for an install like I described above? And I'm aware you can usually edit it, but I can't and that's kind of the whole problem lol.

Comment: how long you install  Ubuntu 16.04 on you laptop?have you ever met the problem? if your computer can regular work before, you can install the ubuntu 16.04 again

Comment: Well I can't login since I don't have drivers that allow me to use my key board and mouse (problem that started this whole thing). Do you know how do this through the root terminal in grub? I've had this OS for like 5 days, three of which it has been unuseable. I've never had this problem but I must have caused it. Considering how dependent stuff was on this resolv.conf file, the CPU wouldn't delete it without me telling it to. So I 100% am at fault, I don't have a problem with the OS per say, I just am at a point where it may be easier to install a new one if that makes sense

Comment: try the wired keyboard,normally,the mouse and keyboard will drive.   maybe you can use the bootable disk, enter the live Ubuntu, try to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` and the other problem. restart the system. if it is not,perhaps you can try to reinstall the Ubuntu.

Comment: You **don't** ever manually edit the /etc/resolv.conf file. It says so right in the file. Any edits that you might make only get overwritten on the next boot. Also, what does the /etc/resolve.conf file have to do with your keyboard/mouse not working? You could boot into root access via GRUB, remount the hard disk as RW, and then `sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: To fix the mouse/keyboard problem I need to run the dpkg option in recovery mode. It can't fetch files however, due to resolv.conf missing. Thus making that missing file the problem that, when solved, fixes all the others

Answer (score 0):

To recreate /etc/resolv.conf...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `mount -o rw,remount /`
  - `sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
  - `reboot`

**Update #1:**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: So the symbolic link already exist. Rebooting and attempting to boot normally puts me right back to an unresponsive keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Laptop or desktop? USB keyboard/mouse? RF keyboard/mouse? When did this start? What version of OS? Tell me more.

Comment: Laptop, no available USB keyboard, USB mouse doesn't work, not sure what RF means to be completely honest, 16.04 LTS Ubuntu, started about 3 days ago I think. Didn't seem to be a problem until I needed to update drivers, then not being able to revealed missing file problem

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if everything (keyboard/mouse) works again. At least that will eliminate a problem with your installed OS.

Comment: Are there any mounting commands I should run? And should I use the same version of Ubuntu or a different one

Comment: No, boot whatever version of Ubuntu Live DVD/USB you have. I just want to see what happens with the keyboard/mouse.

Comment: Well I did it before and the same problem with the keyboard/mouse happened. I can try again when I set up my USB

Comment: What do you mean "set up my USB"? Plug the mouse directly into a computer port. Do you have Windows installed? Does the keyboard/mouse work there?

Comment: By set up my USB I mean make my USB a bootable disk again. The mouse didn't work when I tried it before. I only have Ubuntu, nothing dual booted with it

Comment: Since all of this has nothing to do with /etc/resolv.conf, I'd recommend deleting this question, and starting a new question for the keyboard/mouse problem. Keep the facts there pertinent to that problem.

Comment: I know why I can't use a keyboard or mouse, the drivers are missing. I can't download them because I can't fetch successfully from the root. I know that doesn't work because I don't have a resolv.conf file. Everything leads back to the missing file because the solution to every problem doesn't work due to that file missing. It has everything to do with the missing file

Comment: I thought that we had proved that the /etc/resolv.conf file exists (when I showed you how to recreate it). Let's do it again... in `terminal` type `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. Not being able to use the network in the root account is normal. Not having a resolv.conf file would cause DNS failures (ie: named addresses like www.ebay.com, but not numeric addresses like 8.8.8.8). If you use your normal account, the network should work to download files... although I don't know of any keyboards/mice that don't work at all without special drivers.

Comment: Commands that need to find that file say it doesn't exist, any peek into the file system says it does. That is my problem right now. I also don't think it's missing any special drivers, I think it's missing any drivers at all that make keyboards and mouses work

Comment: Did you do the two `cat` commands that I just gave you? Tell me what other commands say that file doesn't exist? You probably have to reinstall Ubuntu to solve your problem then.

Comment: @user693260 please see the update to my answer.

Comment: Running sudo fsck -f / says that /dev/sda1 is mounted. That sounds like my solid state is the only thing mounted but I could be wrong. Neither cat command is able to find that file or directory. My apologies for taking so long to reply

Comment: I'm frustrated. I'm just not getting the consistent answers that I need. I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry, I appreciate you trying to help